# How to achieve some kind of Play cluster manager?

Tags: playframework, cluster-computing

Play is a real "Share nothing" system, Stateless model like PHP.
When it comes to clustering, Zend delivered a solution called Zend Cluster Manager.

- WhitePaper => http://static.zend.com/topics/Session-Clustering-ZSCM-WP-0610-EN-A4.pdf
- ESCHRADE article => http://www.eschrade.com/page/zend-server-cluster-manager-4c2a2f38 plus the comments on this article

Do you know existing Java opensource resources than could complement Play framework to achieve quite the same thing or an interesting part of it ?

This question targets the following points :

- Configuration, deployment and monitoring management as described for Zend cluster manager
- The way Zend Cluster manager works as it's not based on storing session information in a Db, neither nfs sharing session, neither session-persistent load balancing and works without changing any source code. It's not that bad approach.

If some things serving that purpose change for Play release 2 (for example i don't know the eventual added values in this area of Akka included in this future relase), then my question is more oriented for this release. After all, Play is presented as a whole platform not following servlet approach so a whole platform as a whole solution like php + zend cluster manager would be a killing platform :)

Answer (score 1):

Any java distributed caching solution (or any caching solution that has a java client) would probably delivery what you are looking for. Here is a related questions to java cache alternatives: [Distributed Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1486895/distributed-caching)